# Specifying noexcept function conditionally

Tags: c++, noexcept

Let's say I have such function declared `noexcept`:

```
int pow(int base, int exp) noexcept
{
    return (exp == 0 ? 1 : base * pow(base, exp - 1));
}
```

From my very little, but slowly growing knowledge of C++, I can `noexcept` when I'm certain that function will not throw an exception. I also learned that it can be in some range of values, lets say that I consider my function `noexcept` when `exp` is smaller than 10, and `base` smaller than 8 (just as an example). How can I declare that this function is `noexcept` in such a range of values? Or the most I can do is leave a comment for other programmers that it should be within some certain ranges?

Comment: A function either throws or not. You can condition `noexcept` on how different **types** behave, not the **values** of those types

Comment: I'm reading Scott Mayer's effective modern c++, and he says that they can be noexcept in some certain ranges. But He didnt say much about this specification, that's why I'm asking about it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a condition for `noexcept`, but that condition must be a constant expression. It cannot depend on the value of parameters passed to the function, becaue they are only known when the function is called.

From [cppreference/noexcept](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec):

> Every function in C++ is either non-throwing or potentially throwing

It cannot be both nor something in between. In your example we could make `base` a template parameter:

```
template <int base>
int pow(int exp) noexcept( base < 10)
{
    return (exp == 0 ? 1 : base * pow<base>(exp - 1));
}
```

Now `pow<5>` is a function that is non-throwing, while `pow<10>` is a function that is potentially throwing.